# command line prompt macOS

Tags: macos, command, line

My prompt on command on my mac looks like this:

username@computer ~ %

I've never seen the '%' sign here- it's usually a '$'- any ideas as to what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, % sign is the same like $ sign.

Comment: Interesting, I've just never seen it before. Thanks for your input!